# How to configure in .vimrc , execute current file python f9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, vim-plugin

I'm newbie in this editor but it's complex to configure vimrc. I know and understand that everything stay there but I don't understand how to configure, specifically the code. On the other hand, I am writing Python code using Vim. Every time I want to run my code, I type this inside Vim

```
:w !python
```

This gets frustrating, so I was looking for a quicker method to run Python code inside Vim. If somebody can I help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: It has been answered lot of times

Comment: my question is where add or put this link? inside of .vimrc ? maybe i have made a mistake because i have copied settings of another guy and i don't understand anything. thank you for your time mr.

Comment: Add the line in ~/.vimrc

Comment: I did that but when I run my code or file inside vim , i have this error and this is the reason which I thought that it was the wrong way round.

E15: invalid expression: %
E116 :invalid arguments for funcion shellscape (%)
E15 : invalid expresion : shellscape(%)

I hope that you can help me , regards

Answer (score 2):

You've very close. The following works in my config:

```
nnoremap <F9> :w<cr>:!python %<cr>
```

First, it enters the command to save the file (`:w`). Then it tells the shell to have python (`!python`) run the current file (`%`).

Comment: my question is where add or put this link? inside of .vimrc ? maybe i have made a mistake because i have copied settings of another guy and i don't understand anything. thank you for your time mr.

Comment: Yes, inside your vimrc. The vimrc file is essentially a list of commands that vim runs whenever it starts up. Therefore, to make this key mapping "stick," it should be entered as a line in the vimrc. [Here's](https://github.com/wbadart/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) my vimrc if you'd like an example.

Comment: I did that but when I run my code or file inside vim , i have this error and this is the reason which I thought that it was the wrong way round.

E15: invalid expression: %
E116 :invalid arguments for funcion shellscape (%)
E15 : invalid expresion : shellscape(%)

I hope that you can help me , regards

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your error. Could you post a paste/gist/whatever of your full vimrc along with the output of `vim --version`?

Comment: I have the version VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 23 2017 12:10:29)
Included patches: 1-197, 322, 377-378, 550
and this is my .vimrc file.  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iceiice/.vimrc/master/README.md

Comment: Do it w/o `shellescape`, as it appears in the response.